# How to write a UnitTest for Components with parameters in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.x

I would like to write a UnitTest in CakePHP 3.2 for a Component with parameters, but the CakePHP-Docs says nothing about how to do so (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-components).

I assume that I have to pass the necessary parameters in the `testInitializing()` method:

```
/**
 * Test subject
 *
 * @var \App\Controller\Component\Bandit\EpsilonGreedyComponent
 */

 public $EpsilonGreedy;

/**
 * setUp method
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function setUp()
 {
     parent::setUp();
     $registry = new ComponentRegistry();
     $this->EpsilonGreedy = new EpsilonGreedyComponent($registry);
 }

/**
 * Test initial setup
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function testInitialization()
 {
     $config['epsilon'] = 0.1;
     $config['arrViews'] = array('1', '2', '3');
     $config['arrInteractions'] = array('1', '2', '3');
 }
```

The Test fails because the parameters are unknown to the UnitTest.

Does anyone know how to pass the parameters?

In the Component I save the paramters like the following:

```
`public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);    

    $this->setEpsilon($config['epsilon']);        
    $this->setArrViews($config['arrViews']);
    $this->setArrInteractions($config['arrInteractions']);
}`
```

Comment: Aren't the parameters part of the constructor?

Comment: @Oldskool I pass the paramters onload per array. As far as I know, I can't pass them per constructor. In the Components `initialize`-Method I load the the following way:
`   
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);    
        
        $this->setEpsilon($config['epsilon']);        
        $this->setArrViews($config['arrViews']);
        $this->setArrInteractions($config['arrInteractions']); ...`

Comment: *I can't pass them per constructor.* - You can. 2nd arg of the constructor. http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.Controller.Component.html#109

Comment: @burzum That helps, thanks!